# How do I limit Code Completion to show only public and protected members?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, code-completion, delphi-xe6

Is there a way to show only public and protected members of an object I am using in the Code Completion window? When I type a dot character after the object name in the editor, I don't like to go though the unnecessary list of standard objects, windows handles, and private members that I don't care about. I am sure it has its uses, but I personally don't care about them.

Comment: i dont think that this is possible. because of inheritance there is no difference between the methods of an object and its ancestors.

Comment: You can right-click on the popup window and choose "Sort by Scope", which at least puts them in a more reasonable order. I don't know of any way to just arbitrarily decide whether you want to see any of the content, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I'm afraid there is no way for that unless you manage to find IDE addon which would do that but I haven't heard for any such addon to exists so far.

Comment: If there's the possibility of finding an add-on to do such a thing, then I would assume that you could write an add-on.

Comment: I belive you could but that addon woud probably have to be a compleete replacment for default code insight. And I'm not even sure if you can simply replace just code insight. Maybe you would have to compleetly replace whole code editor.č Unfortunately documentation for making IDE addons is pretty terrible.

Comment: @SilverWarior Not necessarily. For example, MMX includes a "IDE Search Enhancement" function that is capable of hooking into the IDE search and add "history" items there.

Comment: @SilverWarior CNPack comes with a Code Insight replacement.

Comment: I had I feeling that I heard of some addon to have that but I wasn't sure. So I have only written that there is posibility for that.